# Is it more efficient to pass a List or individual List Items as method arguments in Java?

Tags: java, list, methods, parameter-passing, pass-by-value

Assuming I have a list of 100 strings. Is there a difference between the following two approaches in performance (or any other difference)

1.

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3"....."s100");        
foo(myList);

private void foo(List<String> myList) {
    // logic to choose 2 strings from the list
    //do something with -- str1 and str2
}
```

2.

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("s1", "s2", "s3"....."s100");    
// logic to choose 2 strings from the list
foo(str1, str2);

private void foo(String myStr1, String myStr2) {
    //do something with -- myStr1 and myStr2
}
```

Since Java passes the reference(as values) of the List or individual Strings I am assuming those arguments will just hold (copies of) references/addresses. So I am leaning towards passing the entire list.

The above will be a utility method and I want to put the 'logic to choose 2 strings from the list' inside the foo method so callers don't have to repeat that logic before calling; but I am concerned about sending a large list as argument.

Thanks for help.

** ***Edit*** :**
Yes I am looking for Performance concerns.

And `List<String>` probably wasn't the correct example. Think of it as a `Map<String,Long>` (City,Temperature). And the logic will be to always choose Chicago and LA and `foo` will operate on the temperatures. Note that this logic will always be the same and callers would just repeat the same code in approach #2.

Comment: Should it really be `foo`s responsibility to choose two strings or just operate on them?

Comment: I don’t think this can be answered without knowing more about the use case for the method.  Unless your question is about performance, in which case the answer is that the choice does not matter in the slightest.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils `foo` will specifically need those 2 string values. But it does not have to be `foo`s responsibility to perform the logic to choose those strings. But note that the logic will be the same, and repeated by callers should they be asked to do it. Therefore i want to put it inside `foo`.

Comment: @VGR yes my question is mainly about performance. So its not a concern sending a huge list as a parameter? Is this because only the list's reference will be passed as value and not the entire list?

Comment: If your question is about performance then that should be in the subject line. 'Better' is a very ambiguous word. You also have 'and any other difference' in the questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recommend you ignore potential difference in performance (which would be negligible in this case) and focus entirely on clarity of your code. In other words, the question is not which is more efficient but which better reflects the intention of the method you are calling. If `foo` is a method which would naturally expect two arguments (such as `storeFullName`) then it should be passed two arguments. If it would naturally expect to select two values from a list (such as `printTwoLongestStrings`) then it should take a collection.

You might also consider the principle of giving each method a [single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In that case it might make sense to have separate methods for selecting the two values and doing something with them:

```
Pair<String, String> longestPair = getTwoLongestStrings(list);
printStrings(longestPair);
```

** Edit **

Your question has clarified that you are focused specifically on performance and you provided more detail of your use case. Specifically you are asking if there is a difference in performance in passing a list or two values to a method. Yes there is a difference. I ran a trial calling an empty function 10 billion times with two String arguments and with a list. The list call took 24 secs and the separate argument call took 13 secs. It's likely that other physical hardware will show different results. It's also possible that JVM optimisation is not making this a fair test.

```
public class PerfTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList("a", "b");
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (long i = 0; i < 1E10; i++) {
            func1("a", "b");
        }
        long time2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (long i = 0; i < 1E10; i++) {
            func2(list);
        }
        System.out.println((time2 - time1) + "/" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - time2));
    }

    private static void func1(String s1, String s2) { }
    private static void func2(List<String> sl) { }
}
```

However my answer above still stands: if you are calling a function 10 billion times then it might be worth optimising but it is much better practice to start with a focus on clarity and then use profiling to focus code-tuning effort if that is required.

Comment: +1 for clarity of code. Clarity is king in the vast majority of cases, and unless you think this is the bottleneck in your code, there are other things you can optimise without sacrificing readability.

Comment: Thanks @sprinter . I wonder why there is a difference in favor of the individual arguments? Since Java will be passing the List's 'refrence by value' and not the entire list to the method; so it appears like passing 1 referrence vs. passing 2 references. And passing 1 reference should take lesser time?

Comment: The performance difference, if any exists at all, is so small as to be utterly useless to care about.  The difference will be storing the two values inside the method and outside; passing them around is not even worth caring about.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I agree that the difference should be ignored. However I'd still be interested in any explanation of the time difference in the test I wrote. I don't think your comment explains why the List reference is so much slower.

Comment: You haven't shown how you measured things.  Getting accurate Java benchmarks is _extraordinarily_ difficult.

Comment: @Gadam I can't explain the difference but I stand by my recommendation to ignore it and focus on clarity. If you feel this has answered your question then please accept the answer.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry I'm not sure what you mean. The code I posted indicated how I measured the difference. I also tried switching the two tests around and the result was the same: the list reference is significantly slower.

Comment: @sprinter I think I will mark this as an answer but I am still intrigued, as you seem to be, why the list argument performs slower. This is also important to me because I will use that method in a Big Data solution, and expect it to be called millions of times when my solution scales.

Comment: @Gadam yes I'm interested also but not really an expert on the inner workings of the JVM so can't really answer the question. As was pointed out in the comments above, the method I've used is pretty dodgy (i.e. just comparing system clock) so it's possible it's not a fair test. I'll post a separate question and see if anyone knows enough to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking if a List argument is passed by reference.  It is.  In the compiled machine code, for the list argument just a single pointer to the list object instance will be passed to the function.  There is no reason to be concerned about having a large list as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend only using a `List` as an argument if the method is interested in the list itself and not only its items, e.g. it plans on modifying it.

For the other cases, if you have a fixed number of arguments, you should have each argument be it's own parameter. But your case suggested that you have a variable number of arguments. For this you could also use varargs:

```
private void foo(String... strings) {
    // `strings` is an array now
}
```

This has the advantage that the caller can choose to either invoke your function using single objects, or an array:

```
foo("Hello", "World");
```

or this

```
String[] strings = new String[]{"Hello", "World"};
foo(strings);
```

or even this:

```
List<String> strings = ...;
foo(strings.toArray(new String[0]));
```

If you have concerns about turning your list into an array, stick with passing the list itself.